# Ionic 3 & Angular 4 - Cannot read property level of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

A user can create a language and select their level.

However when this page loads i get an error saying "Cannot read property 'level' of undefined".

I assume because there is no language object that has been created yet? How do i initialize one, without setting every property of the language object to "" or null or false. Whats the best solution to my problem?

I tried use the ? operator like so language?.level but that did not work here.

LanguageCreate.html

```
<ion-list-header>
            Level
            <ion-badge item-end color="primary">{{language.level}}</ion-badge>
        </ion-list-header>
        <ion-item no-lines="">
            <ion-range min="1" max="5" step="1" snaps="true" [(ngModel)]="language.level" color="primary">
                <ion-icon range-left small color="primary" name="level"></ion-icon>
                <ion-icon range-right color="primary" name="level"></ion-icon>
            </ion-range>
        </ion-item>
```

LanguageCreate.ts

```
export class LanguageCreatePage {

    language: {
        name: string,
        code: string,
        native: string,
        level: number,
        isTeaching: boolean,
        isLearning: boolean,
    };
    isReadyToSave: boolean;
    type: any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
                public navParams: NavParams,
                public modalCtrl: ModalController,
                public viewCtrl: ViewController,
                public auth: Auth,
                public user: User) {




    }
```

Comment: use typesafe **`?`** operator `{{language?.level}}`

Comment: @Aravind i tried that i still get the same error msg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just initiate empty object and error will go away.

```
language = {}
```

but its better to change some stuff export Language model to separate file
and add '?' to the properties so you make them optional;

```
export interface Language {
        name?: string;
        code?: string;
        native?: string;
        level?: number;
        isTeaching?: boolean;
        isLearning?: boolean;
}

export class LanguageCreatePage {

language: Language = {}
isReadyToSave: boolean;
type: any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
            public navParams: NavParams,
            public modalCtrl: ModalController,
            public viewCtrl: ViewController,
            public auth: Auth,
            public user: User) {




}
```

Comment: I tried adding this in the constructor but i get a msg saying type {} is not assignable to type {name: string,......}

Comment: Updated make them optional with ?

Comment: I create this interface in the models/ folder?

Comment: Yes in model folder.for best practice move them to separate file create interface or class and name like language.model.ts.

Comment: best practise is to create `interface` if they are used as user defined data type

Comment: ill give this a go and get back to you shortly

Comment: Ty this is the solution i was looking for . (Im still learning ionic and angular, so refactoring my code every 1h it seems when i find out new things ). thanks again.

Comment: No problem :-) Just pls dont forget to accept answer.

Comment: done, is there some rule when you should use the operator "?"

Comment: when you use ? it means its optional. if you dont use it it means that it should be there and you will be forced to initiate that variable or you will have error.

Comment: just delete for example in name and you will see error. to fix it you need to write language: Langugage = {name: ''}